# How to transcode video formats

Tags: windows, video, h.264

We're converting a bunch of .RM files to .MP4 and wondered what the best way is. Here are the details:

- Convert the files to H.264.
- Keep the filename but add .mp4 to the end.
- Also extract a JPG image of the video at about 5 seconds in for each file and name it the original filename + .jpg.

This is on a Windows system. Is there a free tool you recommend for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg is pretty much the defacto standard app for transcoding video.

http://www.ffmpeg.org/

**Convert to h264/mp4:**

```
ffmpeg.exe -i inputFile.rm -vcodec libx264 -s 320x240 -acodec libfaac outputFile.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, Sam. A few follow up questions: 1) In that call to ffmpeg, how do you tell it to keep the video's aspect ratio and frame rate? 2) How do you tell it to keep the original filename? 3) How do you extract a JPG frame at 5 seconds into the video?

Comment: @Alex, ffmpeg has a million command line options and can do almost anything.  I'd recommend researching the specific things you want to do and if you don't find the answers ask specific questions.  I don't know the answers off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I'll do some digging :)